# Python lock: lock between different python script execution

Tags: python, locking

I have a problem where I would like to create a lock that would still work between different python file executions. I have tried the `locket` library as below

In file `test_lock_start.py`:

```
import locket
import os

lock_path = os.path.join("./", "test_slot.lock")
test_lock = locket.lock_file(lock_path, timeout=2)
test_lock.acquire()
print("Ryan acquired Lock")
print("Ryan is dancing around")
```

If I run `test_lock_start.py`. It would output:

```
Ryan acquired Lock
Ryan is dancing around
```

In `test_lock_end.py`:

```
import locket
import os

lock_path = os.path.join("./", "test_slot.lock")
test_lock = locket.lock_file(lock_path)

try:
    print("Shanne trying to acquire lock")
    test_lock.acquire()
    print("Shanne acquired lock")
    print("Shanne should not be unable to acquire the lock!!!")
    print("Shanne is dancing around")
except:
    print("Unable to acquire lock")
    print("Shanne unable to dance")
finally:
    test_lock.release()
    print("Released Lock")
    print("Shanne can now acquire the lock to dance")
```

If I `run test_lock_end.py`. It would output:

```
Shanne trying to acquire lock
Shanne acquired lock
Shanne should not be unable to acquire the lock!!!
Shanne is dancing around
Released Lock
Shanne can now acquire the lock to dance
```

This is not what I intended, the output I wish for is:

```
Unable to acquire lock
Shanne unable to dance
Released Lock
Shanne can now acquire the lock to dance
```

Comment: That's because the `test_lock_start.py` has terminated so it cannot hold the lock (the library is meant for a running program).  Try adding a `time.sleep(100)` to the end of `test_lock_start.py` and try to start `test_lock_end.py` as is, it will hang until the `test_lock_start.py` finally exits as you have coded.  You will need to `test_lock.acquire(timeout=0)` in the `test_lock_end.py` to get the output you desire.

Comment: What I really want is even if `test_long_start.py` terminates, the lock is still functional. After calling `test_long_start.py`, a file `test_slot.lock` is created, I wish for `test_lock_end.py` to still use that lock

Comment: That library will not address your desired use case.  You might be looking for [`filelock.SoftFileLock`](https://py-filelock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#filelock.SoftFileLock) for your desired use case.

Comment: I think it might have the same problem when test_lock_start.py ends, the lock file is automatically deleted for some reason

Comment: You might have to build your own solution then by referencing those implementation and make a version that is suitable for your use case.